# How to modify array elements?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have `labels` which is an array. I want to replace `Catch & Bowled` to `Caught & Bowled` similarly `run` to `Run Out`.

What I tried was loop through array and replace that particular string.

Code:

```
 let labels = Object.keys(wickets); <--- wickets array of objects of type let

    console.log(labels);

   for(var i=0;i<labels.length;i++){
        if(labels[i] === 'catch & bowled'){
          labels[i] = 'Caught & Bowled';
        }else if(labels[i] === 'run'){
          labels[i] = 'Run Out'
        }
    }
```

When I again `console.log(labels)` they are not modified why so ?

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: because JavaScript is case-sensitive, so your === statements never produce a true match

Comment: @ADyson How can I replace or modify it ?

Comment: by matching the actual string you want to match. Do you understand what "case-sensitive" means? e.g. `if(labels[i] === 'catch & bowled')` needs to become `if(labels[i] === 'Catch & Bowled')` because  `'catch & bowled'` is not equal to `'Catch & Bowled'` - one uses capital letters and one does not.

Comment: @ADyson Yes I understand case sensitive but then what is the solution to my problem ?

Comment: Surely it's obvious?? you need to make it so the string you're comparing to matches the one in the array...including matching the case of the letters correctly. See my edited comment above, or the answers below. Any of them will do the job.

Comment: Why downvote ? This question is not a duplicate.

Comment: downvotes are not given for duplicates...duplicate votes are given for that. Hover over the downvote button to see reasons why downvotes are given. I didn't downvote but I can sort of see why people might

Comment: @ADyson If I have 100's of elements and if I want to change only 2 or 3 strings then looping over entire array is not efficient any other technique which can be used ?

Comment: Well you could try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find (although it might well just use a loop internally anyway, I don't know). BTW really you can do this kind of basic research for yourself you know, you are not facing a new or undiscovered problem here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because comparison of string is  js is case sensitive, Try the following

```
if(labels[i].toLowerCase() === "catch & bowled".toLowerCase())
```

If you want to check for equality of values of string than it is always better to convert both the string characters to same case. Like in this example both the strings are converted to a string of lowercase characters.

Comment: If I have 100's of elements and if I want to change only 2 or 3 strings then looping over entire array is not efficient any other technique which can be used ?

Comment: @stonerock I think this method is efficient as the worst case time Complexity of this comes out to be O(n), where n is the size of the array.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you wanna have a comparison between strings it is always save to use

```
labels[i].toUpperCase() == 'catch & bowled'.toUpperCase()
```

`.toUpperCase()` converts a string to upper case and at the end you'll have both of the strings in upperCase or lower case if you use `.toLowerCase()`